# Empty String Input as bit representation

Tags: c

This must be one of the most silly questions ever asked, but my brain seems not to be working at all at the moment. For testing purpose I need the bit representation of the empty string
to do some hardware debugging.

In other words, the input to a C-function would be the empty string, ie, "", now I would like to know how I can represent the empty string as a 64-bit value. Is this just a sequence of 64 Zeros or do I miss here something?

Thanks!

Comment: It would only be 64-bits if the hardware was designed that way.  An empty string would be all zeros.  Of course I suppose there might be a null character, which does have a value, that entirely depends on your implementation I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

What a "C-string" is, is an array of characters with a zero-element; which decays to a pointer to its first element in most contexts. Also, the converse is usually accepted: a pointer to char is (often) assumed to be a pointer to (a part of) an array of characters which has a (subsequent) zero-element.

If you interpret "empty string" as array of 0 elements, there really is no concept of that in the C language.
If you interpret "empty string" as array of N elements of which the first element is a 0, the bit representation of that 1st element is `CHAR_BIT`binary 0's (usually 8).
If you interpret "empty string" as pointer to NULL, the bit representation of that pointer is implementation defined, but comparing it to `0` must yield "true".

```
/* ERRATA: where it says "is a string" please read "can be interpreted as a string" */
char arr_string[10]; /* if any element is 0, this is a string */
char *ptr_string; /* if it points to a valid object accessible as `char`
                  ** and a subsequent valid char is 0, this is a string */

strcpy(arr_string, "foobar"); /* arr_string[6] == 0 */
ptr_string = arr_string;

test_string_empty(arr_string);      /* not empty */
test_string_empty(ptr_string + 6);  /* empty */
test_string_empty(NULL);            /* unknown */
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the string terminator has a value of 0. The 64-bit representation would indeed be 64 zeros.

Answer (score 0):

C string termination character is `\0` (all bits set to zero). The remaining bits won't necessary always be zeroes: if the string is emptied via setting its first char to `\0`, the other chars won't change. A sequence of 64 bits set to zero is *one* representation of an empty C string.

Answer (score 0):

The first char would be '\0', which would be a null terminator. In the memory the previous char from what the was before it was set to NULL would still be there. So lets string = Hello World, then string = \0. The memory would look like '\0', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!'.
So if you initialize string to null. It would first be a char of \0 and the rest would be bits set to zero.